# iphone accessing or modifying properties of objects in an array

Tags: iphone, objective-c, arrays, properties

How would I access the properties of an object stored in an array?

something like:

```
[myArray objectAtIndex:0].intProperty = 12345;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to cast the object first.

`((MyObjectType *) [myArray objectAtIndex:0]).intProperty = 12345;`

Answer (score 0):

First, you will need to store the ID in a variable, like

```
(id) myObject = [myArray objectAtIndex:0];
```

Then you can manipulate it:

```
myObject.intProperty = 12345;
```

And store it again:

```
[myArray removeObjectAtIndex:0]; // Remove it before setting it again
[myArray insertObject:myObject atIndex:0];
```

EDIT: Or you could use Jacob's way, which is much better :)

Answer (score 0):

Setting the property by its synthesized setter is shorter (and, to my eyes, cleaner to read and comprehend):

```
[[myArray objectAtIndex:0] setIntProperty:12345];
```